# Publishing assets in Laravel Plugin with Tag

Tags: php, laravel, plugins

In [Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#publishing-file-groups), it is mentionned that I can assign a tag to 1 or several assets so that I can publish it with :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=mytag
```

I tried to use it like that:

In MyPluginServiceProvider

```
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../config/kendo-tournaments.php' => config_path('kendo-tournaments.php'),'custom-tag-name']);
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/migrations'], 'custom-tag-name');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/seeds' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/seeds'], 'custom-tag-name');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/factories' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/factories'], 'custom-tag-name');
```

And then I tried to publish it:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=custom-tag-name
```

But it doesn't publish anything:

> Nothing to publish for tag [custom-tag-name].

Any idea why???

Comment: Is your MyPluginServierProvider registered in app.php with the other service providers?

Comment: oooo. no it wasn't. You can put it as an answer!

Comment: :) no worries, happens to me all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your provider possibly doesn't exist in your app.php along with the other providers.

Double check that your provider is set up there, then repeat the publish command.

If this is a package that will be public facing, it would be worth adding it to the readme (adding the provider before running publish) because it is frequently missed.